# search extension for Radiant CMS on Heroku?

Tags: search, content-management-system, heroku, radiant

Can anyone recommend a good Radiant CMS search extension with decent documentation that works on Heroku?  The only one I've found that seems to work is the Google Custom Search one but it is not extendable and has ads.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at spinx_search for radiant?

https://github.com/radiant/radiant/wiki/Search-Extension

Comment: I don't think Sphinx works with Heroku unfortunately, or this would be a great solution.